# Error conexión c# Firebird

Tags: c#, firebird

Tengo este método de conexión :

```
public bool LogearseFirebird(string Cif, string PWD)
{
    bool oReturn = false;
    string connString =
                "User=SYSDBA;" +
                "Password=masterkey;" +
                "Database=C:\\FirebirdDB\\USUARIOS.FDB;" +
                "DataSource =localhost;" +
                "Port=3050;" +
                "Dialect=3;" +
                "Charset=NONE;" +
                "Role=;" +
                "Connection lifetime=15;" +
                "Pooling=true;" +
                "MinPoolSize=0;" +
                "MaxPoolSize=50;" +
                "Packet Size=8192;" +
                "ServerType=0;";

    FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(connString);
    conn.Open(); 

    String sql = "SELECT NOMBRE FROM TBL_USUARIOS WHERE CIF=" + Cif + "AND CONTRASENYA=" + PWD;
    FbCommand com = new FbCommand(sql, conn);
    FbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        oReturn = true;
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();
    return oReturn;
    }
}
```

y en el `conn.Open()`, me da el siguiente error:

> connection rejected by remote interface

El servicio de `firebird` lo tengo funcionando correctamente y los directorios en teoría los tengo bien, ¿Por qué se puede dar éste error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Vale , con esta cadena de conexión sí que funciona :

```
        private  static FbConnectionStringBuilder parametros_conexion = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
        private  static FbConnection conexion = new FbConnection();
        parametros_conexion.DataSource = "localhost";
        parametros_conexion.Port = 3050;
        parametros_conexion.Database = @"C:\FirebirdDB\USUARIOS.FDB";
        parametros_conexion.UserID = "SYSDBA";
        parametros_conexion.Password = "masterkey";
        parametros_conexion.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;
        conexion = new FbConnection(parametros_conexion.ToString());
```